# How do I install a PFX certificate file into Ubuntu so Curl trusts it?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, curl, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux 2. I am making a `curl` request to a web service running on the Windows side using a self-signed certificate. I receive this error:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I'd like to add the cert to the local store. I have a `.pfx` file available. I know I can use `-k` but I want to use other command line tools against this server.

How do I do this?

#### My own trials

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername server -connect server:443 > foo.pem
openssl x509 -in foo.pem -inform PEM -out foo.crt
sudo cp foo.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

This looks plausible but didn't work, `curl` still has the same complaint.

I also tried to use a `DER` version.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/windows_cert.crt
openssl x509 -in windows_cert.pem -inform PEM -out windows_cert_der.crt -outform DER
sudo cp windows_cert_der.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

#### Give up

Don't worry, I started following some of the replies here.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate

But got nowhere, its obviously a very hard problem in the world of computing.

I've found that a few months back they added a switch to the command line tool I need to use that ignores certificate problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `openssl` command to convert nearly any certificate format to another. PFX is another name for a pkcs12 container.

If you can extract the cert in PEM format curl should be able to use it.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -clcerts -out cert.pem
```

This may ask you for a password which will be the one used to secure the PKCS12 file

You want to use the output `cert.pem` file with the `--cacert` curl command line option not `-k`

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. Can you elaborate on "installing" the certificate into a store so its trusted by any client tool?

Comment: You might want to try putting the DER encoded file in `/usr/share/ca-certificates`  rather than in `/usr/local...`

Comment: The `-clcerts` option is for client certificates. Didn't you guys mean `-cacerts`? By the way, not every pfx contains the certificate chain, unless of course the certificate is self-signed.

Comment: I don't really know what I mean, I don't know about certificates, I just want tools running on Ubuntu to trust my development HTTPS website with a self-signed certificate. I literally don't care how its done, I just need my life back.

Comment: I'm suggesting that the `update-ca-certificate` tool is not looking in the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificate` directory and you should put your cert into `/usr/share/ca-certificate` for it to be added to the trusted set

Comment: @user188737 no, the OP said it was a self signed cert it shouldn't matter which you use, but using the client cert covers the situation you mentioned of not having a CA chain.

Comment: Hello, I converted my .pfx certificate this way but after opening it in KDE GUI, I can't unlock the new .pem cert because it said - password is wrong. I used same password/passphrase everywhere pasting it, so not sure what password is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Under the Debian family the *distribution* way of handling a trust certificate is as follows (reverse engineered by looking at update-ca-certificates):

I will use **myca** as a standin name for your ca (or self-signed) cert and **myca.crt** as the file with the certificate (DER or PEM). The .crt is mandatory.

- Make directory under /usr/share/ca-certificates

  - `mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/myca`
- Put the ca.crt in it

  - `cp ./ca.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/myca/`
- Run dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates, choose *ask* to selectively add new trust anchors and select in the second screen your new myca/myca.crt and press *OK*

  - `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`

To do it more programmatically

After you made the directory and put your cert in:

```
echo myca/myca.crt >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf
/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
```

This last method does not record the configure setting in /var/cache/debconf/config.dat so if you run dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates or update the ca-certificates package, your new trust anchor may disappear again. Running update-ca-certificates is safe.

To get only the certificate from a pfx with self-signed certificate:

`openssl pkcs12 -in my.pfx -nokeys -out myca.crt`

And enter the password to open the pfx.

Adding a self-signed certificate to the root level central trust repository does mean that everyone who possesses its private key gets ways to do MITM attacks on your server.